# MapR control management gives connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapr

I have installed a cluster including 3 nodes on amazon Ec2. I just stopped all instances , however after restarting all insatnces while accesingth e control console using 9443 port it gives me connection refuse error

Do I neeed to restart the MapR services and how?

Thnaks

Comment: I just ceck warden on all my nodes # service mapr-warden status..all says its runnign and active..I dont why I can not access the mapr via MCS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the status of Webserver as it provides access to MCS.